# How to change a label text when I hover on different buttons in qt?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I have 5 buttons in my window qt app. I would like to set a label text, which is a description for each process on hovering above the button. How can I do that?

Comment: Sounds like you want [Tool Tips](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-widgets-tooltips-example.html)

Comment: @dave No, I want to set the text into a label

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use eventFilter for this.

```
bool MainWindow::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event)
{
  if (obj == (QObject*)ui->pushButton) {
    if (event->type() == QEvent::Enter)
    {
        ui->label_3->setText("Your text");
    }
    else if (event->type() == QEvent::Leave){
        //Clear text when mouse leaves
        ui->label_3->setText("");
    }
    return QWidget::eventFilter(obj, event);
  }
  else    return QWidget::eventFilter(obj, event);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

QEvent::HoverEnter and QEvent::HoverLeave can do this for you. Set an event filter (https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/eventsandfilters.html) on your QPushButton and you are good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using `QPushButton` in your UI, you can reimplement the following methods :

```
virtual void enterEvent(QEvent *e)
{        
    setText("mouse in");
}
virtual void leaveEvent(QEvent *e)
{       
    setText("mouse out");
}
```